# How to pass parameter to controller from route beside Request in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel

My controller has two parameter Request and my parameter which I want to pass from route. I'm passing the parameter to controller from route as follow,

```
Route::get('/home/{id}', 'HomeController@home');
```

and received it as,

```
public function home(Request $request, $id){
    echo $id;
}
```

Parameter passes the value correctly but slow to load.
When I load the page **/home/12** then it's loading very much slowly and that's why my markup and style are not loading properly. For testing I pass the Id with get request then it ok but when I passing through url as parameter then not working as well.

Comment: the issue of slow loading is certainly not from the route, its either your web server or system is slow or poor application logic e.g. loops ...which web server are you using? apache or nginx, or are you using `php artisan serve`?

Comment: I'm using php artisan serve. is there have any coding error?

Comment: not a coding error `php artisan serve` is sometimes slow. Try using php native server or consider laravel homestead